# Subquerys on Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have this problem...

```
 select 
  (select  
    To_Char(
       REPLACE (
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             xmlagg(xmlelement("a", to_char(dt_atualizacao, 'dd/mm/yyyy')) order by dt_atualizacao).getClobVal(),
           '</a><a>', ', '),
         '<a>', ''),
       '</a>', '')
     ) xx
    from (
      select  map.nr_atendimento,
              trunc(map.dt_atualizacao) dt_atualizacao
      from    material_atend_paciente map
      where   1 = 1
              and map.nr_atendimento = ecf.nr_atendimento  -- is HERE the problem
              and obter_estrutura_material(map.cd_material,'G') = 15
      group by map.nr_atendimento, trunc(map.dt_atualizacao)
    ) yy
     group by nr_atendimento, dt_atualizacao
  ) dt_execucao_mat
FROM
  tasy.hvc_envio_conta_faturamento ecf
WHERE 1=1
  AND ecf.dt_alta BETWEEN inicio_dia(:DT_INICIAL) AND fim_dia(:DT_FINAL)
;
```

when I execute this command, oracle send a error

ORA-00904: "ECF"."NR_ATENDIMENTO": identificador inválido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

tks for help

Comment: Generally, you can only reference objects one level of nesting up.  You could reference `ecf` in the `dt_execucao_mat` subquery but not in the further nested `yy`.  One alternative would be to construct your query as a join.  Depending on the Oracle version, you might also be able to use an `outer apply`.  Since you are grouping by `nr_atendimento`, do you need to filter by `nr_atendimento` in the inner query?  Could you just join to the result of the `group by`?

Comment: tks for you ansewrs ... my oracle version is 11g (11.2.0.4.0).